# Complex dto based result sets with EF and MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

ok lets say I have a collection of these ...

```
public class ReferenceLookup
{
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public CompanyReference Buyer { get; set; }
    public CompanyReference Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

I need a collection of these as results where any of the pieces exist ...

```
public class ReferenceLookupResult
{
    public SIHead SIHead { get; set; }
    public Company Buyer { get; set; }
    public Company Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

SIHead == invoice

Companies have related tables that contain external references for the company
I somehow (if possible) want to write a single linq query that can do this in a way that exposes me a queryable set of  `ReferenceLookupResult` if possible,
how I would get these pieces is quite complex though

for example here's how I currently get a collection of companies by reference ...

```
public IQueryable<Company> ByReferences(CompanyReference[] refs)
{
    var refStrings = refs.Select(r => r.System + "|" + r.Ident);
    return GetAll().Where(c => c.CompanyTaxIdentifiers.Any(cti => refStrings.Contains(cti.ExternalReferenceSystem.DisplayName + "|" + cti.Reference)));
}
```

... i think i need multiple collections of companies and a collection of invoices where one from each set makes up 1 result dto

here's how I get invoices by reference ...

```
public IQueryable<SIHead> GetAllByRefs(ICollection<InvoiceReference> refs)
{
    var keys = GetAll().Select(i => new { Id = i.SIHeadId, Number = i.InvoiceNumber, Supplier = i.SupplierCompanyAux.CompanyId }).ToList();
    var resultItemIds = keys.Where(k => refs.Any(r => r.InvoiceNumber == k.Number && r.SupplierId == k.Supplier)).Select(k => k.Id).ToArray();
    return GetAll(resultItemIds);
}
```

an invoice reference is an invoice number and a supplier reference
all invoices are at their root generated by suppliers.

**Options considered so far**

- Create a sproc and call that (not queryable though I would think)
- Create a view and add that to the context (EF Code First treats this like a normal entity set)

I'm thinking the latter might be the way to go, but in the past each time I've had a view for something I've ended up replacing it longer term with something LINQ based.

Answer (score -1):

Using a view to produce the complex result set seems to be the best option in my case of the options presented in the question however ...

I found that with a slight architectural change in the business process I wouldn't end up in this situation at all, resulting 2 or 3 simpler requests rather than 1 complex one requiring a "special case" like this to be handled in the call handling logic.